# join_table in many to many relationship in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, join, many-to-many

I have an issue in handling the join table for many-many relation ship . there is my entities and their relationship :
[image: email <--> email_receiver <--> employee]

**Email.class :**

```
@Entity(name = "email")
@Table(name = "email")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "email_generator", sequenceName = "email_seq")
public class Email {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "email_generator")
@Column(columnDefinition = "int", name = "email_id")
private int emailId;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "email_receiver", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "email_id")}
        , inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")})
private Set<Employee> receiversID;
/* other stuff */  
}
```

**Employee.class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1, name = "employee_generator",sequenceName = "employee_seq")
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "employee_generator")
@Column(columnDefinition = "int" ,name = "employee_id")
private  int employeeId;
/*other stuffs */  
}
```

I wrote a sql command to join(`inner join`) the `email_receiver` and `email`tables based on the email_id  . the sql command is totally correct and work properly .here it is :

```
  public List email_join_emailReceiver(int receiverId){
    EntityManager entityManager = HibernateUtils.getEntityManager();
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select email.* , email_receiver.receiver_id \n" +
            "from email inner join email_receiver\n" +
            "on email.email_id=email_receiver.email_id\n" +
            "where email_receiver.receiver_id=?1");
    query.setParameter(1,receiverId);
    List receiversList = query.getResultList();

    return receiversList;
}
```

the result of this sql command has these columns :
[image: result of joining]

but my main problem is that I can't read the `receiversList` (return value of the `query.getResultList()`) because the list is type of `lang.object` and I don't know how to get the
values of the list like : email_id & subject & content & ... .
I need to get the values of the column that mentioned in the above picture .
I also tried casting (cast the `object` to `Email` ) but I got the exception that it can't do casting .

Please let me know your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution that could solve this problem . I have to define a class that I want to do execute the query on it , here in this example it would be `Email.Class` and it will change this part of the code like this :

```
public List<Email> email_join_emailReceiver(int receiverId){
EntityManager entityManager = HibernateUtils.getEntityManager();
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select email.* , email_receiver.receiver_id \n" +
        "from email inner join email_receiver\n" +
        "on email.email_id=email_receiver.email_id\n" +
        "where email_receiver.receiver_id=?1",Email.class);
query.setParameter(1,receiverId);
List<Email> receiversList = query.getResultList();

return receiversList;
}
```